# How can I the userId before an account has been created?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know the title is a bit of a oxymoron; however, I have a register form that also takes more details from the user such as first name, last name etc.

Inside the Register method of the account controller, I have added a Members object, populated it with the data, however, I need the GUID (UserId) of the account being registered to be stored as the "MemberId".

The user MUST have clicked register to get into this actionresult method but no userId is created until program flow has left.

How can I get the userId of the registered account as it returns null? Any help is appreciated. Sorry for the ambiguity.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterForm model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.RegisterViewModel.Email, Email = model.RegisterViewModel.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.RegisterViewModel.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                var members = new Members()
                {
                    MemberId = new Guid(User.Identity.GetUserId()), 
                    // Obviously the above returns null because there is no userId yet.

                    FirstName = model.Members.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.Members.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber = model.Members.PhoneNumber,
                    Role = model.Members.Role

                };
                _context.Members.Add(members);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: You could call UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.RegisterViewModel.Email) by passing model.RegisterViewModel.Email in order to get back registered user detials.

Comment: Thanks, using UserManager returns the userId and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using EntityFramework, after calling `UserManager.CreateAsync` the property for `user.Id` will have been updated.

So you can use the user id like this:

```
MemberId = new Guid(user.Id)
```